# Integrate Google Chrome into Windows Favorites

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Is there a setting or plugin to integrate Google Chrome's bookmarks into the Windows Favorites system? I want Chrome to use the same folder structure (`%UserProfile%\Favorites`) that all my other applications use.

Comment: I guess you can do this. But I am afraid, to automate it, you have to write code. First get your bookmarks exported as HTML, write code to parse HTML, create directories according to your bookmarks folder structures, in direcotries create shortcuts `*.url` as the address of your bookmarks content and name of the bookmarks as your filename. Then Simply paste the shortcuts of root folders bookmarks in the `Favorites` folder. I am afraid, you won't get the tree view fo your bookmarks folders. `Favorites` doesn't support tree view.